# Positioning an entire kinect skeleton in the center of 3D space

Tags: java, processing, kinect, simple-openni

Okay I have been searching for this problem everywhere, truth be told asked a similar question at the processing forum and no-one answered on it. So I took a freedom to ponder yours guy brains a bit. 
So I have a skeleton in P3D and every time its recognized by SImpleOpenNI it just draws it in a relation to the kinect, but how would I go about programming it that every time it gets recognized it gets centered or at least start it so that the entire scene is centered around certain kind of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Capture the world coordinates of some joint (I believe that the hip or torso joint is better for this), and then subtract those coordinates from the coordinates of every joint. Your hip joint will be at (0, 0, 0) and all the other joints will be centered around that one.

Comment: The problem with that is that the kinect draws skeleton almost randomly as of now and draws them slightly differently. If I understand what you are saying the subtraction number would always be the same?

Comment: No, they would not be the same in every frame: they would be the coordinates of the hip joint in every frame. Can you show me the code you're using to draw the skeleton?

Comment: Hey Jose thank you for the respnse here is the code  [link](http://pastebin.com/eHSFg7Cz)